# 'Argument types do not match' when using ProjectTo after Automapper migration from v8 to v9

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

After migration to latest version of AutoMapper(from v8 to v9) I have issue with ProjectTo method. When projecting from ICollection to IReadOnlyCollection I get System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'.

```
public class Source
{
    public ICollection<int> Collection { get; set; } = new HashSet<int>();
}

public class Destination
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<int> Collection { get; set; } = new HashSet<int>();
}

public class Profile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public Profile() { CreateMap<Source, Destination>(); }
}

//This line throws exception
var mapped = mapper.ProjectTo<Destination>(src);
```

I just wonder if this is expected behavior or bug. I did not find any related changes in changelog.

Comment: Bug of course. Most likely caused by this "fix" - [#3187 Match destination enumerable types with it's enumerable for LINQ](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3187) from [9.0 - Improvements/Features](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases) list.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3199